# Telegram API - Send message: Send URL with variable

Tags: php, html, telegram-bot

I have problems sending URL with variables, such as:

```
$url= "https://google.com/{$var}";
```

If I want to send a link via message to a telegram group, I get an error.

My code:

```
...
$sendMessage->parse_mode = 'HTML'; 
$sendMessage->disable_web_page_preview = true; 
$sendMessage->text ='<a href='.$url.'>inline URL</a>' ;  
...
```

The URL only supports pure string. But when I concatenate the string with a variable (as I mentioned above) it gives me the following error:

```
Exception unreal4u\TelegramAPI\Exceptions\ClientException caught, message: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unexpected end of name token at byte offset 8
```

I have Composer installed correctly and it is updated. I have php 7.0.

I have an alternative to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `str_replace()` to escape URL

> All <, > and & symbols that are not a part of a tag or an HTML entity must be replaced with the corresponding HTML entities (< with &lt;, > with &gt; and & with &amp;).

Please refer to [HTML-style](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style) section.

Comment: @Martin It's Telegram parser, not real "HTML"